# Should we ONLY say the Lord's Prayer?

Tags: gospel-of-matthew, prayer, textual-discrepancies, greek, translation

In In Matthew 6:9, the Greek it literally says:
"Thus therefore pray you" or "Οὕτως οὖν προσεύχεσθε ὑμεῖς".

Is Jesus saying that we should pray like that and **only** like that? Initially I would think not as Matthew records Jesus praying in many other ways too, but it seems like He is giving them a blanket "pray this" statement. So what is He saying?